# Simple Byte Encryption Not Working

Tags: c#, encryption

When the message is decrypted, the characters are one less than the original. Example: H Will be G

I have tried to debug the code by printing out values and all goes well until trying to divide by 100000 and multiplying by the date

Here is the code I used: 
I didn't include the Main Method Here

```
    public static string encrypt(string input)
    {
        string final;

        string date = DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString().ToString();

        var datetime = int.Parse(date.Replace("/", ""));
        List<int> semi = new List<int>();
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input.ToCharArray());
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            int y = bytes[i] * datetime / 100000;
            semi.Add(y);
            Console.WriteLine(y);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", bytes));

        final = string.Join(":", semi.ToArray()) + ":" + date;
        return final;
    }


    public static string decrypt(string input)
    {
        string final;
        string[] raw = input.Split(':');

        int date = int.Parse(raw[raw.Length - 1].Replace("/",""));
        var dump = new List<string>(raw);

        dump.RemoveAt(raw.Length - 1);
        string[] stringbytes = dump.ToArray();


        List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();

        for (int i = 0; i < stringbytes.Length; i++)
        {
            int x = int.Parse(stringbytes[i]);
            Console.WriteLine(x);

            x = x * 100000 / date;
            byte finalbytes = Convert.ToByte(x);
            bytes.Add(finalbytes);

        }
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", bytes.ToArray()));
        Console.WriteLine(date);
        var bytearray = bytes.ToArray();
        final = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytearray);

        return final;
    }
```

Comment: `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);` Don't need to call ToCharArray()

Comment: @fahadash i have removed ToCharArray() and it has no change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the low precision datatype `int` to store the result of the division. I have changed the type to `double` and it works

```
    public static string encrypt(string input)
    {
        string final;

        string date = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("MMddyyyy");

        var datetime = int.Parse(date);
        List<double> semi = new List<double>();
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            double y = bytes[i] * datetime / 100000;
            semi.Add(y);
            Console.WriteLine(y);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", bytes));

        final = string.Join(":", semi.ToArray()) + ":" + date;
        return final;
    }


    public static string decrypt(string input)
    {
        string final;
        string[] raw = input.Split(':');

        int date = int.Parse(raw[raw.Length - 1].Replace("/", ""));
        var dump = new List<string>(raw);

        dump.RemoveAt(raw.Length - 1);
        string[] stringbytes = dump.ToArray();


        List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();

        for (int i = 0; i < stringbytes.Length; i++)
        {
            var x = double.Parse(stringbytes[i]);
            Console.WriteLine(x);

            x = x * 100000 / date;
            byte finalbytes = Convert.ToByte(x);
            bytes.Add(finalbytes);

        }
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", bytes.ToArray()));
        Console.WriteLine(date);
        var bytearray = bytes.ToArray();
        final = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytearray);

        return final;
    }
```

Here is a fully working console app http://ideone.com/Rjc13A

Comment: I am surprised it worked considering you still have int division of  `datetime / 100000` going on. if you did `datetime / 100000.0` that would fix it

Answer (score 2):

It's likely a rounding error from integer division. when doing integer math it is very possible that  `((x * date / 100000) * 100000 / date) != x`, in fact the only time it will be `== x` is when `date % 100000 == 0`.

Fix the rounding errors introduced by your int division and it should fix your problem.

---

**P.S.** I would also be very hesitant to call this "encryption", there is no secret key, all the information required to decrpt the message is in the message itself. You are only relying on the fact that the algorithm is secret which is practically impossible to do with C#. I would rather call what you are doing "Encoding", because to decode something that is encoding all you need to know is the algorithm.

Comment: More like "garbling" than encryption

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a number truncation issue.  In your decrypt method, the division will actually create a double instead of an int - If you do the math it turns out to have decimal places.  Since x is an integer it will be cutt-off.

The following should work:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < stringbytes.Length; i++)
  {
            var x = double.Parse(stringbytes[i]);
            Console.WriteLine(x);

            x = Math.Round((x * 100000) / date,0);
            byte finalbytes = Convert.ToByte(x);
            bytes.Add(finalbytes);

  }
```

Also, as a side note why are you creating your own encryption algorithm?  Could you not use one that already exists?

Comment: I wanted to try something new and forgot about rounded values. I'm rusty with programming.